# form:input and form:password aren't submitting to controller but form:hidden is... huh?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I'm an experienced programmer who has many years experience with the Spring 3.0 framework, but this one has me a bit puzzled.

Inside of my form, I have three different scenarios playing out, my  and  tags aren't being submitted to my controller (I've checked for any binding exceptions using an @InitBinder method, but there aren't any errors... Here's my form tags:

```
<form:form commandName="accountCommand" method="POST">
  <form:hidden path="action"/> <%-- THIS WORKS --%>
  <%-- ...  --%>

  <%-- These don't submit anything to the controller  --%>
  <div>
    Old Password: <form:password path="oldPassword"/>
    New Password: <form:password path="newPassword"/>    
  </div>
</form:form>
```

Here's the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="editAccount.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String accountPost(@ModelAttribute AccountsCommand accountsCommand,
      @RequestParam(required=false) String stripeToken,
       Principal principal, ModelMap model) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException, AuthenticationException, InvalidRequestException, APIConnectionException, CardException, APIException
  {
    // Once inside here, the "accountsCommand" object doesn't have the expected mapped values... except the <form:hidden...> values are set accordingly.
  }
```

Here's the command object:

```
public class AccountsCommand
{
  private String oldPassword;
  private String newPassword;
  private String action;

  public String getOldPassword()
  {
    return oldPassword;
  }
  public void setOldPassword(String oldPassword)
  {
    this.oldPassword = oldPassword;
  }
  public String getNewPassword()
  {
    return newPassword;
  }
  public void setNewPassword(String newPassword)
  {
    this.newPassword = newPassword;
  }
  public String getAction()
  {
    return action;
  }
  public void setAction(String action)
  {
    this.action = action;
  }
}
```

I've put breakpoints in the setter methods, and can confirm that they are not called for the "password" fields.

Here's the JS code I use to submit the hidden field (which works):

```
$("#planSubmit").click(function () {
  $("#action").val("updateAccount");
  $("#accountCommand").submit();
  return false;
});
```

EDIT:

Here is the actual HTML code as it appears on my site:

```
<form id="accountCommand" action="/account/editAccount.htm" method="POST">
    <input id="action" name="action" type="hidden" value=""/>

    <div>
      <input id="oldPassword" name="oldPassword" type="password" value=""/>
      <input id="newPassword" name="newPassword" type="password" value=""/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have confirmed that the password inputs do indeed have values when they are being submitted by outputting their values right before I call the `$("#actionCommand").submit()` method... but once I'm in the controller, those values are empty.

Comment: Post generated html source code, please.

Comment: Posted html source as requested @libik

Comment: did you check if you've made any typos in the controller part? Like, the names of the input fields.

Comment: @Ritikesh, thanks for the comment... as far as I can tell there are no typos.  I think all the pertinent information to verify if there's a typo is included above... this error happens on three different fields, so I think the odds of me having a typo in three different fields is fairly low (at least I hope it is!  Otherwise I'm terrible at typing!  lol)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

Below all of my hidden fields, I had added another `<form>` tag... so I had two forms on the same website.

This was causing all the inputs below the second form to fail when they were submitted to my controller.

It was a copy/paste fail, as I had copied code from another part of my app.

So for those of you who are interested... I just deleted the second `<form>` tag and it fixed my problem

Live and learn!